# Is it possible find by key in sequelize PostgreSQL?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, findall

I want to find the data based on a single word out of a group of words.
I have a field called "value" in my PostgreSQL DB, if I give "housing" then it should return the data but here it is not. how to do this?
here is the content in a model:

```
value: DataTypes.STRING
```

Here is my code:

```
const category = await models.Category.findAll({
        where: {
            value: {
                $ilike: housing
            }
        }
    });
```

here is my test data:

```
"value": "Ghar, Housing, Finance, Property, Zameen, Sampati, Salhagaar, Salahkaar, Vakil, Prashikshak , Consultant, Finance, Money, Paise, Account, Legal, Kanooni, Kayde, Kaayde, Nyay, Vakil, Dhan, lawyer, loan, home, house, loan, credit, bank, Ghar, Makaan, Housing, Loan, Finance, Arthik, Jamin, Zameen, Sampatti, Consultant, Vyvastha, Salahkaar, Rupiya, Paisa, Kaydo, Kaydakiy, Nyaypurn, Nyay, Vasihat, Khatu, Kayda, Credit, Poramorshodata, Prasikhok, Ukil, mortgage, मॉरगेजSalahkar, PrashiksakSalahkar, CounslarSalahkarah, Prashikshakaaalosagarsalahegaara,prashikshakaparamarshadata,prashiksakaConsultant , Counselorconsultant ,konsultant , counselor , counselar",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the wild card symbol '%'.  Here's an example:

```
where: { value: { $like : '%housing%'}}
```

This would match both "housing" and "roughhousing"... so you might want to refine a little.